# Automapper: Collection of DTOs inside DTO not mapping

Tags: .net, entity-framework, automapper

I currently have the following models:

```
public partial class Observation
    {
        public Observation()
        {
            Answers = new HashSet<Answers>();
            ObservedEmployee = new HashSet<ObservedEmployee>();
        }

        public int ObservationId { get; set; }
        public int WorkgroupId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public int ObservationTypeId { get; set; }
        public string WorkstationCode { get; set; }
        public string ObservationNotes { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
        public int CreatedById { get; set; }
        public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDatetime { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual ObservationType ObservationType { get; set; }
        public virtual Workgroup Workgroup { get; set; }
        public virtual Workstation WorkstationCodeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ObservedEmployee> ObservedEmployee { get; set; 
    }
}


public partial class Answers
    {
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public int ObservationId { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public int? SubOptionId { get; set; }

        public virtual Observation Observation { get; set; }
        public virtual OptionCatalog Option { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestionCatalog Question { get; set; }
        public virtual SubOptionCatalog SubOption { get; set; }
    }
```

And the corresponding DTOs

```
public class ObservationDTO
{
    public int ObservationId { get; set; }
    public int WorkgroupId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int ObservationTypeId { get; set; }
    public string WorkstationCode { get; set; }
    public string ObservationNotes { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDatetime { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AnswersDTO> Answers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ObservedEmployeeDTO> ObservedEmployee { get; set; }
    public WorkgroupDTO Workgroup { get; set; }

}

public class AnswersDTO
    {
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public int ObservationId { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public int? SubOptionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public string OptionText { get; set; }
        public string SubOptionText { get; set; }
    }
```

When I map an Observation to an ObservationDTO I would like the ICollection to be an ICollection. With that in mind I made the following mappings

```
cfg.CreateMap<Answers, AnswersDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.QuestionText, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Question.QuestionText))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.OptionText, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Option.OptionText))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SubOptionText, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SubOption.SubOptionText));
        cfg.CreateMap<Observation, ObservationDTO>()
            .ReverseMap();
```

Here is where I call the mapping and below that is the code for the service call

```
public IEnumerable<ObservationDTO> GetUserObservations(int id)
    {
        var observations = _observations.GetUserObservations(id);
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ObservationDTO>>(observations);
    }

public IEnumerable<Observation> GetUserObservations(int id)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            return _context.Observation
                .Where(obs => obs.CreatedById == id && obs.CreatedDatetime >= date)
                .Include(i => i.Answers)
                .Include(i => i.Workgroup)
                .ToList();
        }
```

And here is the response I get from the backend

```
{
"observationId": 11,
"workgroupId": 1,
"locationId": 1,
"observationTypeId": 1,
"workstationCode": "DFW",
"observationNotes": "I would enter notes here if I had any.",
"createdDatetime": "2019-01-30T17:19:27",
"createdById": 30633,
"updatedById": null,
"updatedDatetime": null,
"isDeleted": false,
"answers": [
  {
    "answerId": 1,
    "observationId": 11,
    "questionId": 3,
    "optionId": 1,
    "subOptionId": 2,
    "questionText": null,
    "optionText": null,
    "subOptionText": null
  }
]
}
```

My issue is that currently, when I get this DTO returned to me, all of the ForMember additions are null. These entries do have values for their text, so I know it's not working correctly. This leads me to assume the Collection isn't getting mapped. I'm rather new to this tool, but I've researched for at least 4-5 hours on this issue specifically, including the documentation, and I'm a little lost. I'm not sure if I've missed a necessary include (I've tried all that I could think of) or if my mapping config is incorrect. If anyone has any thoughts or guidance on this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be the `Option`, `Question` and `SubOption` navigation properties of `Answers` objects are simply `null` because you haven't `Include`d them in the query.